# Why is node.js dependency listed as a depdency so many times in my package-lock.json, but never actually required anywhere else in my application?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to the node.js world, and have inherited an app that uses the [aws-xray-sdk-core](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master) library. I've noticed that the npm package `minimist` is listed as a dependency many times in the [package-lock.json file](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/blob/master/package-lock.json), but when I search to see where the package is actually referenced in the code, it is only showing in the package-lock.json: [image]

Why is this? Is the package not actually used by any of the libraries which list it as a dependency? I'd expect to see it imported using `require('minimist')` if it were actually being used somewhere.

Comment: Vs code generally ignores searching node_modules so you’re not going to see that by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can `npm why minimist` to find out what's requiring it. It's surely there because another dependency depends on it.

More specifically you may wish to run `npm why @types/minimist` if you're concerned about that in particular.